# how to add inner shadow to background without applying it to children elements

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I have a home screen, where I can add tasks. I want the background to be with inner shadow, but all children's elements inherit shadows unnecessarily.

Tried this code:

```js
const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Header />
      <View style={styles.tasks}>
       <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => console.log("add new task")}
        style={styles.iconStyle}
       >
        <Ionicons
          name="ios-add-circle-sharp"
          size={65}
          color="#1B57B8"
          style={styles.iconShadow}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
  },
  tasks: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    margin: -5,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    borderColor: "white",
    borderWidth: 5,
    overflow: "hidden",
    shadowColor: "#484848",
    shadowRadius: 7,
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    flexBasis: "90%",
  },
  iconStyle: {
    alignSelf: "center",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 710,
  },
  iconShadow: {
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 5,
    },
  },
});
```

The add button should NOT inherit the parent's inner shadow, and should apply only it's own styles instead.

Moreover I get the warning:

```
WARN  (ADVICE) View #2265 of type ABI49_0_0RCTView has a shadow set but cannot calculate shadow efficiently. Consider setting a background color to fix this, or apply the shadow to a more specific component.
```